# What is the meaning of "his fire escape" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1276104/synopsis)

> but is winged by another Gat Man, falls from **his fire escape** and
>   blacks out.

What is the meaning of his fire escape ?

Comment: The  user is not asking about *fire escape* but about *his fire escape*. To a learner unaware of the compound noun *fire escape*, the parsing of  *his fire escape* is not necessarily obvious. Consider *his water escape* or *his quick escape*.

Comment: if you admins mark this question as off-topic, then why this question still visible, please delete this question because it gives me blocking warning comes up for delete option. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

> A [fire escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_escape) is a special kind of emergency exit, usually mounted to the outside of a building or occasionally inside but separate from the main areas of the building. It provides a method of escape in the event of a fire or other emergency that makes the stairwells inside a building inaccessible.

[image]

So, he was standing on the fire escape, got hit, fell to the ground and blacked out.